# Using Gekko/APMonitor w/ sensitive information?

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I am interested in using Gekko/APMonitor in Python for solving large systems of nonlinear equations, and for optimization.  I ran a few test cases, and it looks like a really cool piece of software!!  My one concern is around information management: if I understand correctly, gekko sends your model to an external server by default when you solve a model.

My question is: how exactly does this work, and is there a way to fully disable any external information transfer if your model data is confidential?  I know that you can add the flag “remote = False” to run the model without internet access: is this all you need to do?  I saw a lot of additional solver options around html and web-based stuff that defaults to active, so I wasn’t sure whether there was any risk of information being sent externally from those.

Basically, if this transfers information to another computer, I cannot use it at all, but if it doesn’t, it could be one of the most useful pieces of software I have!

As a followup question: if I forget to set “remote = False” on accident, does that mean that all of my model data will be accessible by either the general public or APMonitor developers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Internet communication when using `remote=False` with the Gekko model. The default `remote=True` gives access to additional solvers that cannot be distributed without a license. With `remote=True`, the model and data are sent to the public server and results are returned. Data security is an important issue and there are several mechanisms to address it with Gekko. Here are a few options for an application where there is sensitive data and there is concern about inadvertently sending data to the public server:

- Use a computer with no Internet connection
- Always use the `m = GEKKO(remote=False)` option
- Modify the Gekko library to hard-code the `remote=False` option
- Set up a local APMonitor server for [Windows](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServer) or [Linux](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux) and direct `remote=True` options to that server with `server=10.0.0.10` or the local IP address
- Contact Advanced Process Solutions about setting up an APS-hosted remote dedicated server for sensitive data with data security mechanisms.

The files that it sends and receives are in the local run directory `m.path` that can be viewed with `m.open_folder()`. When `remote=True` option is selected, Gekko sends:

- Model file `gk_model0.apm`
- Data file `gk_model0.csv`
- Variable Classification `gk_model0.info`
- Options and Configuration `measurements.dbs`

The public server returns:

- Results files `results.csv` and `results.json`
- Options file `options.json`

Gekko anonymizes the model variable names unless the `name` option is used to declare the values. Here is an example regression application:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# data
xm = np.array([18.3447,79.86538,85.09788,10.5211,44.4556, \
               69.567,8.960,86.197,66.857,16.875, \
               52.2697,93.917,24.35,5.118,25.126, \
               34.037,61.4445,42.704,39.531,29.988])
ym = np.array([5.072,7.1588,7.263,4.255,6.282, \
               6.9118,4.044,7.2595,6.898,4.8744, \
               6.5179,7.3434,5.4316,3.38,5.464, \
               5.90,6.80,6.193,6.070,5.737])
# regression
m = GEKKO() # remote=False for local mode
# parameters and variables
a = m.FV(value=0); a.STATUS=1
b = m.FV(value=0); b.STATUS=1
c = m.FV(value=0,lb=-100,ub=100); c.STATUS=1
# load data
x = m.Param(value=xm)
ymeas = m.Param(value=ym)
ypred = m.Var()
# define model
m.Equation(ypred == a + b/x + c*m.log(x))
m.Minimize(((ypred-ymeas)/ymeas)**2)
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.solve()
print('Local path: ',m.path); m.open_folder()
# show final objective
print('Final SSE Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

Below is a summary of the files that are sent and received. As can be seen, the original variable and parameter names are replaced with `v1` and `p1-p5`.

**Sends Model File**

```
Model
Parameters
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    p3 = 0, <= 100, >= -100
    p4
    p5
End Parameters
Variables
    v1 = 0
End Variables
Equations
    v1=((p1+((p2)/(p4)))+((p3)*(log(p4))))
    minimize (((((v1-p5))/(p5)))^(2))
End Equations

End Model
```

**Sends Data File**

```
p4,p5
18.3447,5.072
79.86538,7.1588
85.09788,7.263
10.5211,4.255
44.4556,6.282
69.567,6.9118
8.96,4.044
86.197,7.2595
66.857,6.898
16.875,4.8744
52.2697,6.5179
93.917,7.3434
24.35,5.4316
5.118,3.38
25.126,5.464
34.037,5.9
61.4445,6.8
42.704,6.193
39.531,6.07
29.988,5.737
```

**Sends Variable Classification**

```
FV, p1
FV, p2
FV, p3
```

**Sends Options**

```
APM.AUTO_COLD = 0
APM.BNDS_CHK = 1
APM.CSV_READ = 2
APM.CSV_WRITE = 1
APM.CTRL_UNITS = 1
APM.CV_TYPE = 1
APM.CV_WGT_SLOPE = 0.0
APM.CV_WGT_START = 0
APM.DBS_LEVEL = 1
APM.DBS_READ = 1
APM.DBS_WRITE = 1
APM.DIAGLEVEL = 0
APM.EV_TYPE = 1
APM.EV_WGT_SLOPE = 0.0
APM.FILTER = 1
APM.FRZE_CHK = 1
APM.HIST_HOR = 0
APM.HIST_UNITS = 0
APM.ICD_CALC = 0
APM.IMODE = 2
APM.LINEAR = 0
APM.MAX_ITER = 250
APM.MAX_MEMORY = 4
APM.MAX_TIME = 1e+20
APM.MEAS_CHK = 1
APM.MV_DCOST_SLOPE = 0.1
APM.MV_STEP_HOR = 1
APM.MV_TYPE = 0
APM.NODES = 2
APM.OTOL = 1e-06
APM.REDUCE = 0
APM.REQCTRLMODE = 3
APM.REPLAY = 0
APM.RTOL = 1e-06
APM.SCALING = 1
APM.SENSITIVITY = 0
APM.SEQUENTIAL = 0
APM.SOLVER = 3
APM.SPC_CHART = 0
APM.SPECS = 1
APM.STREAM_LEVEL = 0
APM.TIME_SHIFT = 1
APM.WEB = 0
APM.WEB_MENU = 1
APM.WEB_PLOT_FREQ = 1
APM.WEB_REFRESH = 10
APM.BAD_CYCLES = 0
APM.COLDSTART = 0
APM.CTRL_HOR = 1
APM.CTRL_TIME = 60
APM.CYCLECOUNT = 0
APM.PRED_HOR = 1.0
APM.PRED_TIME = 60.0
p1.STATUS = 1
p2.STATUS = 1
p3.LOWER = -100
p3.UPPER = 100
p3.LOWER = -100
p3.STATUS = 1
p3.UPPER = 100
```

**Receives Results**

```
set,             0,            60,           120,           180,           240,           300,           360,           420,           480,           540,           600,           660,           720,           780,           840,           900,           960,          1020,          1080,          1140
p1,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01,   5.5145648367E-01
p2,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00,   1.9269758873E+00
p3,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00,   1.4994292612E+00
p4,   1.8344700000E+01,   7.9865380000E+01,   8.5097880000E+01,   1.0521100000E+01,   4.4455600000E+01,   6.9567000000E+01,   8.9600000000E+00,   8.6197000000E+01,   6.6857000000E+01,   1.6875000000E+01,   5.2269700000E+01,   9.3917000000E+01,   2.4350000000E+01,   5.1180000000E+00,   2.5126000000E+01,   3.4037000000E+01,   6.1444500000E+01,   4.2704000000E+01,   3.9531000000E+01,   2.9988000000E+01
p5,   5.0720000000E+00,   7.1588000000E+00,   7.2630000000E+00,   4.2550000000E+00,   6.2820000000E+00,   6.9118000000E+00,   4.0440000000E+00,   7.2595000000E+00,   6.8980000000E+00,   4.8744000000E+00,   6.5179000000E+00,   7.3434000000E+00,   5.4316000000E+00,   3.3800000000E+00,   5.4640000000E+00,   5.9000000000E+00,   6.8000000000E+00,   6.1930000000E+00,   6.0700000000E+00,   5.7370000000E+00
v1,   5.0188497158E+00,   7.1435979526E+00,   7.2372676473E+00,   4.2633409254E+00,   6.2843733053E+00,   6.9401702878E+00,   4.0544245981E+00,   7.2562214569E+00,   6.8817142874E+00,   4.9027846897E+00,   6.5206897044E+00,   7.3829989336E+00,   5.4175687428E+00,   3.3761797606E+00,   5.4621637320E+00,   5.8972296362E+00,   6.7576688398E+00,   6.2258766659E+00,   6.1137315330E+00,   5.7149697019E+00
```

Submitted data with `remote=True` is not available to other public users, but the [Terms and Conditions](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/TermsConditions) could allow it. There are many millions of optimization problems submitted to the website each year and some of these are currently used to improve the software. In the future, submitted models and data could be be used as training and testing for machine learning to develop better solvers or classify problems into types for automated hyper-parameter selection.